# Prerequisites for developemt on Windows 7 desktop application

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-7

So I am thinking to start developing Windows desktop based application and I want to start with application with windows 7 support.
I know that I need VS 2013 for that but I am not getting any such documentation as to what else is needed? Does the SDK comes with the IDE? what language primarily is used for that.
It would be very nice if anyone could guide me so that I can start development of an app I have been thinking along for a long time.

## EDIT -

Currently I am running Windows10, so will VS2013 run on that?
P.S - Dont close this question thinking it to be out of context. I am a iOS programmer and i just want to widen my skill set.

Comment: Visual Studio comes with everything you need. I would guess C++ or C# would be most often used. I use both. I am using VS2013 and Windows 10. MSDN is your friend: [C# tutorials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Editing my question coz i forgot to mention another query

Comment: I'd go for [Visual Studio Community 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs) instead. It doesn't have the restrictions you'd have, when going with the free Express Edition of VS 2013. There's nothing else you need. Time to hop over and read [Learn to Program for Windows in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399.aspx). Or [Walkthrough: Creating Windows Desktop Applications (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx) if you are impatient.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but can i develop windows 7 supported application on VS 15?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 supports development of desktop applications for all supported versions of Windows (Windows Vista and later). If you want to target Windows 7 you have to make sure, that you aren't using any features, that were introduced in Windows 8 or later. To have the compiler do this for you, you need to define the minimum supported OS as explained under [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx).